# Renewing all provisioning profiles at once

Tags: xcode, provisioning, ios-provisioning

Is there a way to renew all provisioning profiles at once? Thanks to Apple, Xcode 5.0.2 appears to have this function missing and the portal is not helping.

any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can refresh all the provising profiles by opening the preference tab by clicking on Xcode Menu and than select accounts, select your apple account and click view details , there is an refresh button there, click it and it will refresh all the profiles .

Comment: For heaven's sake!!!! PERFECT. I hate when Apple move stuff to other parts of Xcode and then f***ing hide them! THANKS!